# Python - Best way to auto install dependencies

Tags: python, installation, dependencies

I have a python `project` hosted on PyPI.  I've discovered I have some dependency conflicts that need to be pinned.  I know `pip` looks at the `install_requires` key in `setup.py` for dependencies, but I've read it's best to place pinned dependencies in a requirements.txt file.  I've included this file (see below) using `pip freeze`, but I am unsure whether `pip install project` is sufficient to install dependencies as well.

```
# requirments.txt
numpy==1.9.2
pandas==0.16.2
```

I would like to make the simplest installation process for the user. For a package hosted on PyPI:

1. How do I setup requirements to simply `pip install` a project and include all of it's **pinned dependencies** automatically (similar to `conda`)?
2. Must `install_requires=['numpy', 'pandas']` be included?  If so, how do I best set it up to install the pinned versions only.

Comment: I would avoid using `==`, and instead use `>=`. Otherwise, newer versions may be uninstalled.

Comment: The problem is the new version of numpy and pandas breaks my package.